# jstree Reveal the selected child entry

Tags: javascript, jstree

I use

```
$('#jstree-naf').jstree().check_node(value);
```

to selected the entry I need. But I need to reveal the tree until this.

Exemple (currently):

[image]

Should become:

[image]

So, the parents should be reveal.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_open_to` method as below. Check demo - [Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/g7uxbaL1/)

```
$("#jstree-naf").jstree()._open_to( value );
```

Comment: Awesome, does it exists the same thing to close the node ?

Comment: Like the `$('#jstree-naf').jstree().close_node( value );` method?  I updated the fiddle demo from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `select_node(node/id)`. Selecting a node will open the tree to show it. If you don't want it do be selected you can immediately deselect it again.